# using GNURadio in Ubuntu virtual machine: fatal error

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I want to try GNURadio on my Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine. I installed osmosdr and rtl-sdr and I actually tried both sources, but I'm getting this error:

```
Generating: '/home/natalia/Downloads/top_block_NoGUI.py'

Executing: /usr/bin/python -u 
/home/natalia/Downloads/top_block_NoGUI.py

Using Volk machine: avx2_64_mmx_orc
gr-osmosdr v0.1.4-98-gc653754d (0.1.5git) gnuradio 3.7.9
built-in source types: file fcd rtl_tcp rfspace redpitaya 

FATAL: No supported devices found to pick from.

Trying to fill up 1 missing channel(s) with null source(s).
This is being done to prevent the application from crashing
due to gnuradio bug #528.


>>> Done
```

I also created this file as root: /etc/udev/rules.d/20.rtlsdr.rules that contains the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bda", 
ATTRS{idProduct}=="2838", GROUP="adm", MODE="0666", 
SYMLINK+="rtl_sdr
```

because when I do lsusb, I get:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:5686 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:2838 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL2838 DVB-T
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

what else could I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed gr-osmosdr without rtlsdr support; native support for RTL dongles is not in the listing given by gr-osmosdr.

Comment: I also installed rtl-sdr

Comment: But you definitely didn't build gr-osmosdr with rtlsdr support; it says so right there in the output you're posting. See my answer.